# A square matrix with the diagonal and antidiagonal elements different from zero. Looking for some already known property.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, diagonalization

I am interested in the properties of a matrix with elements different from zero only on the main diagonal and antidiagonal, like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
   a & 0 & 0 & h \\
   0 & b & g & 0 \\
   0 & f & c & 0 \\
   e & 0 & 0 & d \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

For example this matrix is the result of a power series based on an antidiagonal matrix C:

$$Z = I + C + C^2 + C ^3 + \cdots$$

Has this kind of matrix some useful property? with respect to

- diagonalization
- eigenvalues eigenvectors
- inverse

Thanks, any information will come in handy.

Comment: Such a matrix can always be written as the direct sum of $2 \times 2$ matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a matrix (with size $n$) of the above form.
Let $P$ denote the permutation matrix whose columns are $e_1,e_n,e_2,e_{n-1},\dots$.  We note that
$$
P^TAP = 
\pmatrix{
A_1 \\
&A_2\\
&&\ddots\\
&&& A_k
}
$$
where $k = \lceil n/2 \rceil$.  If $n$ is odd, then $A_{n}$ is simply a number.  In all other cases, $A_k$ is a $2 \times 2$ square matrix.

What we find that is, for every eigenvector of $A_k$, there is a corresponding eigenvector of $A$.  Also, for any $m \in \Bbb N$, we have
$$
A^m = 
P
\pmatrix{
A_1^m \\
&A_2^m\\
&&\ddots\\
&&& A_k^m
}
P^T
$$
note that $A$ is invertible iff each $A_k$ is invertible.  In this case, we may also take $m$ to be negative.

Suppose that $u$ is an eigenvector of $A_k$. Then define the block vector
$$
v=
\pmatrix{
0\\ \vdots \\ 0\\ u \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\0}
$$
The vector $Pv$ is an eigenvector of $A$. In fact, these give us a complete set of eigenvectors.

Comment: I am interested in the relation between the eigenvector of $A_k$ and the one of $A$? What do you mean by $k$ negative, it seems to be an index to me.

Comment: See my latest edit